# Suppose $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis for some subspace $V$ of $\mathbb R^m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, vectors

Let $b$ be a vector in that subspace. Prove that if $b$ is orthogonal to all three basis vectors, then b has to be a zero vector.

Hint: What is $\|b\|$

I do not know how to start this proof. Thanks in advance for any help i get.

Comment: Since $b$ is in the subspace, can it be expressed in terms of $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know $\langle b, v_k\rangle = 0$ for $k = 1, 2, 3$. But if b is an element in the subspace generated by $v_1, v_2, v_3$, then $b=a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3$ for scalars $a_1, a_2, a_3$ by definition. But, $\|b\|^2 = \langle b, b \rangle = a_1 \langle b, v_1 \rangle + a_2 \langle b, v_2 \rangle + a_3 \langle b, v_3\rangle = 0+0+0 = 0$, so $\|b\|=0$ so $b=0$.

Above I used the fact that any element in a subspace can be written as a linear combination of elements in the subspace, the definition of norm in terms of inner product and the fact that the inner product is additive, so if you are confused you should look into those facts!

Answer (score 2):

As b is in the vector space,
$b=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$ for some scalers $c_i$.
And $\|b\|^2=\langle b,b\rangle = \langle c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3,b\rangle$ where $\langle\,\rangle$ denotes the inner product.  This with inearity of inner product will answer your question.